# Number of non-isomorphic embeddings.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs, topological-graph-theory

Define two embeddings of a graph on a surface to be non-isomorphic if their corresponding dual graphs are non-isomorphic.

How many distinct embeddings (up to isomorphism) are there of a $3$-regular, planar, balanced-bipartite graph onto a $2$-sphere?

Comment: What is the context of this question (i.e. is there any reason you have to suspect that it has a nice answer?). Also can you provide a minimal example of such a $2n$-vertex $3$-regular balanced bipartite graph? It's not immediate to me that such a planar graph must exist.

Comment: @MikePierce I am looking for asymptotics.

Comment: Perhaps you were already aware of this (and it's been a year since the question), but in any case I'll just mention that there is a lot of work on enumeration of "bicubic maps" (i.e., embeddings of 3-regular bipartite graphs), beginning with some of Tutte's earliest papers on planar map enumeration. You can have a look at https://oeis.org/A000257 and associated references. (I do not know about the balance condition, though.)